# Uniform convergence of the series of functions $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (e^{{x}\over{n}}-1) \sin{{x}\over{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis

The series pointwise converges in $\mathbb R.$ In fact the general term $f_n(x)$ is $\sim_{+\infty}$ to ${x^2}\over{n}$ and $\sum {{x^2}\over{n}}$ is a convergent series $\forall x \in R$.

For the uniform convergence I consider interval $[-a,a],a>0$: $|f_n(x)|\le {{x^2}\over{n^2}}\le {{a^2}\over{n^2}}$. Since $\sum {{a^2}\over{n^2}} $ converges, by Weierstrass there is uniform convergence in this interval.

Is there uniform convergence on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Please insert the question (also) in the text of the question (not only in the title). Furthermore it is important to provide content, related information to the question and the own way to attack the question. (Only asking a question by copy+paste is not the way it works, please share the effort with the potential answerer. Showing what you know makes an answer easier to type, and easier to hit the essence of the solution.) Not doing so attracts a lot of downvotes.

Comment: I have edited the solution.It's correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniform convergence of the series on $\mathbb R$ fails. Proof: Recall that if $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on a set $E,$ then $\sup_E |f_n| \to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ But in our problem,

$$\sup_{\mathbb R} |f_n| \ge f_n(n) = (e-1)\cdot \sin 1,$$

and thus we don't have the required convergence to $0.$